# inter vlan routing and access switch default gateway

Tags: cisco, vlan

I have a question. If we have 5 2960 layer 2 switches with vlans 2,3,4,5,6  that they are connected via trunk port to 3850 and we've created vlans(2,3,4,5,6) on 3850 and gave them an ip each in it's vlan range. They all need to ping each other.  does we need to set default gateway on 2960 to it's vlan ip on 3850? or we just need to set that IP on clients in each vlan?
If we make vlan 1 as management does we need to set a default gateway for it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: A laer-2 switch only needs an address in its management VLAN, and the default gateway should be the gateway for that VLAN. Adding addresses on the other VLANs really serves no purpose because it only need the one management address, and the addresses in the other VLANs cannot use the default gateway.

Comment: Thank you ron.is it possible that we don't use default gateway? what could be the scenario?

Comment: Think of the switch management as a PC connected to the switch. It is internal to the switch, rather than external, but it behaves the same way. For a PC (or your switch management) to connect to (or be connected from) a different network, it needs to have a gateway configured.